# VB silverlight for windows phone "System.Xml.Linq"

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am having this line in two of my  windows phone applications :

`Dim doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result)`
in the one of these apps it is working fine , in the other one it seems wrong ...
actually it cant find the object "XDocument"

When i am typing :

`Imports System.Xml.Linq`

it send me bug a warning :

`Warning   2

Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Xml.Linq' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.`

the only diference between the application that works and the applications that sends me back this bug and this worning is that the one is a simple windows phone page (the working one) and the other one is a panorama page :S

any ideas why i am having this warning ??

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need to include the reference to System.XML.Linq first using Visual Studios "add reference" command (right click your project node in the project explorer, add reference).

Comment: but it is supposed not to need this one because i am typing :
<code>Imports System.Xml.Linq</code>

:S

whatever !!! 
thank you ! it worked !! :)

Comment: It does need that one, because you need a reference first on PROJECT LEVEL, then on FILE LEVEL. The project level determines the Version and ID of the file you want to reference, the file level does not. There's actually multiple versions of System.Xml.Linq available. One for 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, etc.